# Multiple file types for downloads

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a web app that can currently download data as a JSON. I want to add the ability for the user to select the file type between JSON and CSV using the system provided dialog. On Windows it is labeled as "Save as type:" with a drop down menu. I can't figure out how to add options beyond all files and JSON OR CSV, not both. As you can imagine I also need to provide differently formatted data based on the type selection. Is this possible using HTML/JS, or is this not possible in a browser?

Currently the download button uses a blob with type: "application/json". I've tried just adding text/csv to it with a comma, but only the last one would register.

I've tried googling for this, but I can't seem to find anything with the search terms I can think of. All the results seem to be about downloading multiple files and not offering multiple file TYPES to download.

I also can't think of any examples of sites doing this so I worry that it isn't possible.

Comment: why not add 2 anchor tags (`<a>`), one of 'em having json download url and another having csv download url ?

Comment: It seemed like a waste to make my own UI elements when there appeared to be built in options for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible using HTML/JS, or is this not possible in a browser?

It is certainly possible to convert between JSON/CSV formats. They're pretty straightforward to serialize/deserialize using string manipulation, provided that all delimiters are known. Whether or not you *should* do it in the browser, or prepare it server-side, depends on your situation and requirements.

> I want to add the ability for the user to select the file type between JSON and CSV using the system provided dialog.

By the time the system dialog is opened, the data is either being streamed, or ready to be streamed to disk. It does not take multiple files and serve the one selected by the user. As @bogdanoff suggested, you'd need multiple download links.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed to know. In my case EVERYTHING has to be done client side, I must have been conflating my experience with Windows apps and browsers. It did look like this was the case.